# MVC site randomly not returning PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, partial-views, connection-timeout

My MVC 4 site uses jQuery Ajax to update parts of my site, and my site is primarily used to modify information in an underlying SQL database. My problem is that randomly the server will not return the PartialView even when running the server locally.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8, and running the server on the Azure platform.

I should rephrase the part about the server not returning it though, because after 19 seconds, the client retries fetching the data, and it normally succeeds, but it returns it twice (only renders once), and each return holds the same data (as it should). Though the site still works, the 19 second delay is the problem.

- /Trace.axd doesn't reveal any problems, other than the 19 second wait
  and status code 200.
- The database connection works well, and the server reaches the end of
  the code where it returns the PartialView to the renderer.
- The same problem occurs trying to call the PartialView directly via a link
  in a browser.
- It occurs an average of once every 20 calls (at least while I'm
  testing it here locally).
- Chrome Developer Tools shows that it fetches 13 bytes of data (which
  I assume is the header) after which it waits the 19 seconds and
  finally receives the full data twice.

My thought is that either there is an underlying problem with my configuration, or with returning PartialViews, though most of the time the site runs just fine.

If I could get some clue as to my next move in debugging this error, or a good theory to the problem, it would be nice.

Kindest Regards

Michael (D3vinno)

Example code from the controller

```
public ActionResult _List_Product() {
  Database db = new Database(Session["database"] as string);
  db.Connect();
  DataTable dataTable = null;
  using (SqlCommand command = db.GetSqlConnection().CreateCommand()) {
    command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT [product].[id], [product].[title] FROM [product]");
    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();

    dataTable = new DataTable { TableName = "product" };
    if (sdr != null) {
      dataTable.Load(sdr);
    }
  }
  db.Close();
  return PartialView(dataTable);
  }
```

And example view

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@{
    string type = "_Product";
}

<p>
    <button class="btn span8" onclick="SetContent('@type', 'new')">New</button>
</p>

<table class="table row-fluid table-condensed" data-provides="rowlink">

@foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in Model.Rows) {
    <tr id="show-@item["id"]">
        <td id="search-@item["id"]">
            <b> @item["title"] </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn pull-right" onclick="SetContent('@type',@item["id"])">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt look like any issue with the partial view. If you have a doubt about that, send some static data rather than hitting the database.

Best option would be to select top 3 rows in the query and look for the output.

I guess it would give some direction to the solution!